# Gatsby - Javascript replace images src from API response

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I am using Gatsby, blog_post.body contain relative path which came from different domain eg:

API url: cms.drupal.com/api/blog/1
Gatsby url: localhost:8000/

I want to replace src from `<img src="/files/images/image.jpg />` to  `<img src="cms.drupal.com/files/images/image.jpg />`

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.blog_post.body}} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution would be to add the domain to the image url on Drupal.

Otherwise if you want to handle it on client side you could do something like this:

Define a variable to hold the url to the cms site like so:

`` const cms = `cms.drupal.com`; ``

and then in the render function do a regular expression to replace all image src urls.

`` const body = this.state.blog_post.body.replace(/src="\//g, `src="${cms}/`); ``

and then

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: body }} />
```